# Need information regarding elasticsearch automation

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to automate elasticsearch query, But do not know how to proceed. My job is to execute simple Get query and get the JSON output and compare it with the expected result. I have tried with HTTP client but it does not support to send JSON payload with Get call. Could anyone help me with elasticsearch client or some other way. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body. Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html